# How to integrate Eirgon EVM execution client into substrate chain

Tags: runtime, evm, client

I am building a substrate based chain (not a parachain) and I require 100% EVM compatibility.  As such, I would like to leverage [erigon](https://github.com/ledgerwatch/erigon) as an EVM execution client and use substrate as the consensus engine and for execution of native runtime based extrinsics.  All EVM transactions and any historical data required from the EVM chain would be provided via the erigon RPC - the substrate chains single responsibility would be for consensus. This would follow a similar pattern of how Ethereum is structured with the beacon chain providing consensus and the execution layer providing block production and validation. I was wondering if anyone would be able to provide some insights on how best to implement this structure. I have heard of the wrapped block model which I believe could be of relevance but would also appreciate insights in regards to block production and block import and any changes required to the client and runtime to support such a pattern.